# PHP and mysql leaderboard wont display information

Tags: php, mysql, leaderboard

I am trying to display mysql data in a table except nothing is being display.

```
<?php
                    $query = $koneksi->prepare("SELECT name,kill,death from `player`");
                    $query->execute();
                    if($query->rowCount() == 0)
                    {
```

Here I am getting the data

```
    {
                        echo "<tr><td colspan='6'><small>There's no player on ban list</small></td></tr>";
                    }
                    while($data = $query->fetch())
                    {
                        echo "<tr><td>".$data['name']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$data['kill']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$data['death']."</td>";
                        $kd = $data['kill'] / $data['death'];
                        echo "<td>".$kd."</td></tr>";
                    }
                    ?>
```

Now I am displaying the data except nothing shows.

Comment: Do you see any error messages? If you dont then did you configure PHP to show you error messages?

Answer (score 1):

`kill` is a reserved word. Try to surround it by backticks like `` `kill` ``